# pick the s3 parquet files from a s3 bucket based on specific column filter condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, parquet

I need to pick the s3 parquet files list from a s3 bucket based on specific column filter condition.

file structure: s3:bucket/folder/file.parquet {inside folder multiple parquet files}

file has information like id,name,address,zipcode,deptno,transactiontime.

deptno=1,2,3,4..etc(int)

transactiontime="2019-10-24T21:14:39.503Z", "2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z".. etc(string)

Now I want to collect parquet filelist from the bucket based on condition deptno,transactiontime (let say deptno=2,transactiontime="2019-10-24T21:14:39.503Z")

How can we achieve this and appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Running a query via AWS Athena is an option for this. You can also use an AWS glue crawler to set up the table in Athena as well. After this, you'll be able to write SQL against the table and filter for the column conditions as needed. The "$path" keyword in an Athena query will return the filename of the result

Answer (score 0):

AWS [Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc) is the tool of choice. What you need is the `WHERE` clause in Athena. The question is very broad, so I can't provide any specific solution. Here is an [article](https://blog.cloudera.com/speeding-up-select-queries-with-parquet-page-indexes/) that should answer your questions.

The first step is to set up Athena with S3. This process is well [documented by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/getting-started.html).

If you are asking for a Python implementation of the query, then [Boto3 Athena Client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#client) is what you are looking for. To be precise, you need the following methods:

- [start_query_execution](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution): Runs the SQL query statements contained in the Query.
- [get_query_execution](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_query_execution): Returns information about a single execution of a query if you have access to the workgroup in which the query ran. Each time a query executes, information about the query execution is saved with a unique ID.
- [get_query_results](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_query_results): Streams the results of a single query execution specified by QueryExecutionId from the Athena query results location in Amazon S3.